# Join LINQ-query with predicate

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I've some problems with a LINQ query in C#.

I have in the database the same tables that have the same structure.
So, today, I've been troubling with my LINQ query.

More details, I want to join some tables using predicates.

I have a function that has two parameters.
The first parameter is some kind of Context (For example, it may be ProductContext, CarContext, CatContext and etc).

The second parameter is a `List<something>` that I will join with my first parameter - Context.

**I do not want a set of methods.**

I've added the sample:

```
    public Element[] GetByIds( MyPredicateContext, Guid[] ids)
    {
        return 
            from id in ids
            join element in MyPredicateContext on id equals element.Id
            select
                new Element
                {
                    Id = element.Id,
                    Description = element.JobDescription,
                };
    }
```

Comment: Why do you want a context as parameter, and not a table ? Or you want both ? And I guess all your elements have not a `JobDescription` property, do they ?

Answer (score 0):

If the query is correct, one basic issue that I can see is the return type is Element array whereas you are trying to return IEnumerable. Maybe doing a .ToArray() on the result set might solve the problem.

Comment: Doesn't matter for this question

Comment: Apologies, maybe I didn't get the issue here, could you please explain further the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry if you are referring to .net Predicate, they are not suitable to be used here. Filip has given a good solution and it could be good start. I would define a common interface between Car, Product and Cat table and pass that interface instead of passing MyPredicateContext just as Filip has suggested. Please note your 3 tables must inherit from this common interface. This way you can pass reference of one of those tables to the method provided by Filip.

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
return MyPredicateContext.Where(element=>ids.Contains(element.Id))
          .Select(e=>new Element()
             {
                 Id = element.Id, 
                 Description = element.JobDescription
             }).ToArray();
```

Comment: Pay attention, there was join

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't create a new IQueryable from an array this will revert to pulling everything in memory and filtering there. You are working with expressions and not c# code when you do LINQ with SQL, this will only work on in memory stuff (IEnumerable).
Your query will work in SQL if you do it like this

```
from element in MyPredicateContext
where ids.Contains(element.Id)
select  new Element
                {
                    Id = element.Id,
                    Description = element.JobDescription,
                }
```

Given that the type of IQueryable where T is an Interface or class.
The end method will look something like this

```
public interface IElement
        {
            Guid Id { get; }
            string JobDescription { get; }
        }

        public Element[] GetByIds<T>(IQueryable<T> myPredicateContext, Guid[] ids) where T:IElement
        {
            return (from element in myPredicateContext
                    where ids.Contains(element.Id)
                    select new Element
                                    {
                                        Id = element.Id,
                                        Description = element.JobDescription,
                                    }).ToArray();

        }
```

There are ways to do it with no Generics but they are a bit more advanced and will be hard to maintain.

Here is a method that will work on all T types and proper IQueryable will produce good sql just as I pointed out is a bit more advanced and you will need to lookup how expression work.

```
public static Element[] GetById<T, Tkey>(IQueryable<T> items,Tkey[] ids)
        {
            var type = typeof(T);
            ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(type);
            var list = Expression.Constant(ids);
            //The names of the properties you need to get if all models have them and are named the same and are the same type this will work
            var idProp = Expression.Property(param, "Id");
            var descriptionProp = Expression.Property(param, "JobDescription");

            var contains = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().First(m => m.Name == "Contains" && m.GetParameters().Count() == 2).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Tkey));
            var where = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.Call(contains, list, idProp), param);

            return (items.
                Where(where).
                Select(Expression.Lambda<Func<T, Element>>(
                    Expression.MemberInit(
                    Expression.New(typeof(Element)),
                        Expression.Bind(typeof(Element).GetProperty("Id"), idProp),
                        Expression.Bind(typeof(Element).GetProperty("Description"), descriptionProp)), 
                        param))).ToArray();
        }
```

Call `GetById(items, new Guid[] { Guid.NewGuid() })`

Comment: Pay attention, there was join

Comment: @Andrew The `Contains` does the same as your join in this case.

Comment: @Filip Cordas. Okay, sorry, it's my mistake, but how class from DataBase may be inherited from IElement ?

Comment: Linq sql -- Region Parameters FIRST
`DECLARE @p0 NVarChar(1000) = '1'
DECLARE @p1 NVarChar(1000) = '2'
-- EndRegion
SELECT [t0].[CODE], [t0].[DESCRIPTION], [t0].[DISPLAYINDEX], [t0].[FILTER]
FROM [BCPACTIVITYPLANRISK] AS [t0]
WHERE [t0].[CODE] IN (@p0, @p1)
GO
Second
SELECT [t0].[CODE], [t0].[DESCRIPTION], [t0].[DISPLAYINDEX], [t0].[FILTER]
FROM [BCPACTIVITYPLANRISK] AS [t0]`

Comment: Your data model needs to have Id property and JobDescription property if your DataBase class has the two properties you can just use it as T

Comment: @Raphaël Althaus as I pointed out I was talking about IQueryable and if its an IQueryable it won't do the same as join. Since he was talking about a Context what I assumed he was working with EF or Linq To SQL.

Comment: DataBase class has the two properties but I can't just use it as T, because IElement is not inherited from my classes in the context

Comment: Change `where T:IElement` to `where T:DataBase` I just used it since I needed something for it.